# Checking for URL in JUnit

Tags: java, selenium, junit

I'm using the selenium RC driver for JUnit testing my application.  Here is the relevant code I am trying to write.  It checks that if the user clicks the link, they are taken to the right place.

```
selenium.click("//td[@id='myLink']/a");
String myURL = selenium.getLocation();
```

However, when the webdriver simulates a "click," it instead opens up a new window.  So now I have the first window open, and the page that I wanted to navigate to is open in a seperate window.  Now, when I try to get the URL, selenium grabs the first URL, so it fails the test case.  How can I make the page open in the same window?  Or, alternatively, how can I get selenium to check the URL of the new window?

**EDIT:** Should also mention, both my first and second window have the same title, so I don't think I can use `selenium.SelectWindow(Title);` for this.

Comment: Selenium-RC has been deprecated several **years** ago, and is no longer being actively maintained. You will get more help if you upgrade your tests to Selenium-WebDriver.

Comment: @SiKing Yeah, but I already started this one test suite using the RC.  Need to finish the tests soon, so I'm just planning on finishing the tests, then refactoring the code later on using web drivers.

Answer (score 0):

Well, with selenium RC being as fickle as it is, I found a work-around for this problem.  Here is the brief overview of how I changed my code:

```
String targetURL = selenium.getAttribute("//td[@id='myLink']/a@href");
selenium.openWindow(targetURL, "myNewWindow");
Thread.sleep(3000);      //wait a few seconds for my page to load

selenium.selectWindow("myNewWindow");
selenium.getLocation();

//do my checks

selenium.selectWindow("originalWindowName");
```

So I retrieve the href myself, open the window using the retrieved URL and with my own custom name.  I then switch the context of the driver to the new window and perform my checks.  Once I am done, I switch my context back to the original window, and continue with my tests.